# How to get a select box to control another select box

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I can't find a nice way to defining this, so I was hoping someone could help.

I have two select boxes (Division and Sub-Division).  When the user comes in, they only see the Division select box.  When they select a division, the sub-division select box appears under it and only shows items for that division.  Much like this.

```
<select name="divisions">
<option value="1">Div1</option>
<option value="2">Div2</option>
</select>

<select name="subdivisions">
<option value="1" division="1">Sub1</option>
<option value="2" division="1">Sub2</option>
<option value="3" division="2">Sub3</option>
<option value="4" division="2">Sub3</option>
</select>
```

So, when I choose division 1, I should see the second select box pop up and only show Sub1 and Sub2 as options in that select box.  When I choose division 2, the second select box should only show Sub3 and Sub4.  I would like to know how I can do this using PHP and javascript easily.

I am using codeigniter to code this page and I've already sent my view the Divisions and SubDivisions objects with the data I need to build the select boxes.  I don't know if I have to convert these objects to javascript or not, but I would like to avoid that if possible.  It sounds like it'll get too complicated to convert my object to javascript arrays and then populate the select box.

Comment: Maybe a silly suggestion but have you tried a simple `if()` statement that checks if a certain checkbox is checked?

Comment: What have you tried? This is a hugely common question and, as such, I can't imagine you'd have much trouble finding resources to help on this.

Comment: Is the data in the second select dependent on the value of the first? So if I choose option 1 in the first box, will the second box show me a different set of choices than if I chose option 2?

Comment: Do you want the user to select the Division and based on his selection the subdivision drop-down loads?

Comment: @Utkanos: I have tried to take the codeigniter object I pass to the view ($subdivisions) and created a PHP script in my javascript to parse the PHP object out and into a javascript object.  This, in my eyes, is very, very messy and easily creates thousands of lines of code to do something that should be very simple.  The problem I'm having is that I can't find a 'nice' way of accomplishing what I want.

Comment: @KA_lin: Yes.  I already have the list of sub-divisions in a PHP object, so I just wanted to create the second select box with all of the possible sub divisions there could be, and then based on the choice in the first select box, only show the sub divisions that related to the division.

Comment: I guess you already found a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are asking HOW to do this? Sorry, I do not see any questions in your post. If you are trying to create a conditional where when one check box is selected, the others become available you can do a couple things.  My favorite is to use jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#divthatholdssubboxes').hide()

 $('#checkbox').click(function(){
       $('#divthatholdssubboxes').slideToggle('slow');
    });

    });
```

I usually put all my checkboxes in a div to hold everything. This is a cool method because it gives your site some dynamic graphical interface, yet still allows you to keep your program logic in tact.

Comment: So you're saying that, rather then having one select box hold all of the secondary options (sub divisions in my case) you create a new select box for each subdivision and only hide or show the select box you need at that time?  I'm just trying to understand everything, sorry.

Comment: no, it still will be one primary checkbox that is always visible with secondary checkboxes in a the div, "divthatholdssubboxes", which will be hidden at first and toggle whenever you check the primary box

Answer (score 0):

For the first part (showing/hiding divisions) you need to do it with javascript, I would use jQuery.

- attach an onChange event listener to the select box http://api.jquery.com/change/
- check the value of the select box http://api.jquery.com/val/
- enable/show the subdivisions select box using val (readonly/disabled attribute) or css http://api.jquery.com/css/

For the second part use the CI form helper to set the value, you'll need some logic to hide the subdivisions as well

- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html (set_select)